# How to get my website approved for AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

I have new website and want to add AdSense.

1. What is the approval process?
2. What kind of programming language can be used?
3. How much content is needed at a minimum?
4. Is Adsense just for English websites? How about for people like me who don't speak English well?
5. How many visitors per day are needed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article that you should read about requirements for Adsense approval: http://allbloggingtips.com/2012/08/27/applying-for-google-adsense-program/

To try to answer your specific questions:

1. You need to apply before your website is approved.  When you apply, your website needs to meet a minimum set of requirements: privacy policy, enough content, original content, no adult content, etc.  [Here are Adsense program policies that your site must follow](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9727)
2. Adsense doesn't care what programming language is used to create your site.
3. I've seen guidance that you need at least 30 articles of 500 words to get Adsense approval.
4. Adsense is available on websites in many languages.  [Here is a list of languages that is supported by Adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9727)  If you don't write English well, I wouldn't apply for Adsense on an English website first.
5. There are no minimum traffic requirements to apply for adsense, only minimum content requirements.    However, you won't get paid by Adsense until you make $100.